# How does the save system of "I Am Alive" work?

Tags: i-am-alive

I just started playing I Am Alive, from X-Box Live Arcade. AFAICS, the game has a different save system. It rewards you **`Retry`** s at certain points to take you to the latest checkpoint, but I am somewhat confused.

1. When I die at some point, and I use a "retry", do I lose my supplements and ammo?
2. When I die at some point, and I run out of "retry"s, where does the game restart? What do I lose? Do I lose my supplements and ammo?
3. If I exit the game at any point to be played later on, where does the game restart? Do I lose "retry"s, supplements, and ammo?

If you can give detailed info on the game's save system, I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all seems to be based on the cut-scenes. From what I have played/seen, I have come up with the fact that any time that the game loads and displays the number of retries you have that is the "Episode." The "retry" locations seems to be based on a checkpoint system that is also dubbed by cinematic views and cut-scenes. As for the supplements, from what I recall it was based on what you had at that cut-scene, anything from that scene to the point at which a retry was used will be lost. I have not started over from an episode, but I would assume that the same is to be said for that type of replay.

I hope that helps.